# C# linq to xml, delete tag name based on next tag

Tags: c#, linq

Delete tag `New` and its content if the next tag is `<b>`

here is my xml file

```
<tag>
    <New>some content</New>
    <b> bold </b>
    <New> content two </New>
    <p> p tag </p>
</tag>
```

output is

```
<tag>
    <b> bold </b>
    <New> content two </New>
    <p> p tag </p>
</tag>
```

here is my code

```
XElement rootImg = XElement.Parse(xml string variable);

IEnumerable<XElement> img =
    from el in rootImg.Descendants("New").ToList()
    select el;

foreach (XElement el in img)
{
    //what am i going to do here?
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach (XElement el in img.ToArray())
{
    var afterElement = el.NodesAfterSelf().FirstOrDefault() as XElement;
    if (afterElement != null && afterElement.Name == "b")
    {
        el.Remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: Add it into you foreach